# C# Return Statement In Try/Catch Not Stopping Program

Tags: c#, return, try-catch

I created a Windows form project with a web browser object. I created a method to reading from a CSV file into a list. And once the list is populated and the form loads, the first item in the list will appear in the website's text box.

I'm using a try/catch block to perform error handling. I noticed that if the file is already open it is showing the message box, but the code continues to run once I close the message box.

It is then throwing an Argument Out of Range Exception when the browser navigates to the web page.

Is it correct that the code continues to run. Should I just add additional error handling before navigating the web browser to the website?

```
private void LoadAccounts()
{
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Doesn't Exist");
        }

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] accountinfo = line.Split(',');
                    accounts.Add(new WaterAccount(accountinfo[0], accountinfo[1], accountinfo[2],accountinfo[3],string.Empty, string.Empty));
                }

            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }

 }
```

This is the code block calling LoadAccounts:

```
public FormWRB()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadAccounts();
        webBrowserWRB.Navigate("https://secure.phila.gov/WRB/WaterBill/Account/GetAccount.aspx");
        buttonExport.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to stop the entire program? Maybe try Application.Exit(); Though, its probably better to stop the program through the normal logic of the entire application, it makes it more maintainable. And yes its correct that the program continues to run, provided that there is more code to run after wherever you're calling LoadAccounts()

Comment: can you please post the code which calls `LoadAccounts`? this would make the answers more profound and more closely related to your problem at hand

Comment: You could make `LoadAccounts()` a `bool` instead of a void then in your catch statement `return false` instead and handle the result accordingly in the code block calling `LoadAccounts()`

Comment: What would be the best thing to do here if I want to make sure that file is closed before the message box is clicked?  Add a message to the user?

Comment: Thank you.  I've decided to handle the result in the code block calling LoadAccounts()

Answer (score 0):

A try catch statement does not stop the program from running, it just affords you the chance to handle an exception. Most commonly logging the exception. 
Essentially what your code is doing is trying to run a block of code, if it catches an `IOException` then display the error message in a message box and the return just terminates the execution of the method.

Here's a solution that could work for you.

```
    private void LoadAccounts()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"{path} does not exist");
        }

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] accountinfo = line.Split(',');
                accounts.Add(new WaterAccount(accountinfo[0], accountinfo[1], accountinfo[2], accountinfo[3], string.Empty, string.Empty));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the code block that handles `LoadAccounts()`

```
    try
    {
        LoadAccounts();
        webBrowserWRB.Navigate("https://secure.phila.gov/WRB/WaterBill/Account/GetAccount.aspx");
        buttonExport.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // Do stuff when file not found here...
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
       // Handle other exceptions here
    }
```

References:
`return` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return
`try catch` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch